# Pass all traffic through my vpn

Tags: networking, ip, iptables, openvpn

After connecting to my open vpn through network manager on linux, it connects bu do not use the vpn to connect to the internet.
my ip table is as below:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto static metric 600 
10.9.10.1 via 10.9.10.5 dev tun0 proto static metric 50 
10.9.10.5 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.9.10.6 metric 50 
48.168.191.5 via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto static metric 600 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.102 metric 600 
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 proto static scope link metric 600
```

I would like to pass all my traffic through my vpn to become secure.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this section in your OpenVPN server's configuration file:

```
# If enabled, this directive will configure
# all clients to redirect their default
# network gateway through the VPN, causing
# all IP traffic such as web browsing and
# and DNS lookups to go through the VPN
# (The OpenVPN server machine may need to NAT
# or bridge the TUN/TAP interface to the internet
# in order for this to work properly).
;push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
```

Uncomment the last line of it. If your configuration file isn't based on the example or otherwise doesn't have that, just put `push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"` somewhere in it.